# How can I list two or more particular chains with iptables?

Tags: iptables

Show a particular chain e.g. DOCKER chain

```
iptables -L DOCKER
```

Show all known chains with

```
iptables -L
```

Is it possible to show *two or more* chains with *one* iptables command?

E.g. show only DOCKER-USER and DOCKER chain, something like this

```
iptables -L DOCKER,DOCKER-USER or
iptables -L DOCKER DOCKER-USER
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can write a script for that. I will assume you have `bash` as your shell.

1. Create `iptables-multilist.sh` in `$HOME`
2. In `iptables-multilist.sh`, paste this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# you may wish to change "-L" to "-nL" or "-nvL"
COMMAND='iptables -L'
# the delimiter you wish to split on
DELIM=','

IFS=$DELIM
chains=($@)
unset IFS
for chain in ${chains[@]}; do
  $COMMAND $chain
done
```

3. Add an alias in `$HOME/.bashrc` for convenience

```sh
alias iptb-L="bash $HOME/iptables-multilist.sh"
```

After restarting your shell you should be able to just call something like `iptb-L INPUT,OUTPUT`.